# You account already has a valid iOS Development certificate in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having a agent access in my organisation. Here the problem is I am not able to access our company distribution certificate in my Xcode 7.3

Here I attached the error message which I got in the Xcode

[image]

Comment: it means in some other mac has already used this certificate , so import the p12 from there surey works

Comment: Thanks for comments.  I export all my certificate and import the p12 file into keychine now its working.

Comment: happy to hear , congratz

Answer (score 3):

As per your screenshot, You downloaded **developer certificate** is already created with the **other Mac**. You need to do is ask that mac user to **export the **public and private certificates** from **keychain access** in his machine and install in your system.

It will give as a p12 certificates. Once this is done surely it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ramesh. Actually i regenerate my our distribution certificate because it has expired and export all my certificate and imported the p12 file in my keychine Access. Now its works

Comment: Hi @ASV. It is not mandatory to accept answers, but it sure it nice to. Can you do so on this one?